# QTcpSocket: Setting LowDelayOption seems to have no effect?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp

I have a Qt GUI application that uses **QTcpSocket** to send and receive TCP packets to and from a server. So far I've had success making the TCP socket connections (there are 2 separate socket connections because there are 2 different message sets. Same IP address for both but 2 different port numbers) and sending and receiving packets. Most of the messages that my application sends are kicked off via push-button on the GUI's main window (one message is sent periodically using a QTimer that expires every 1667ms).

The server has a FIFO (128 messages deep) and sends a specific message to my application that communicates when the FIFO is 1/2 full, 3/4 full, and full. It's tedious to test this functionality by just mashing the send button on the GUI so I had the idea of loading a .csv file that could be pre-filled (the message has several different configurable parameters) with what I want to send. Each line gets read and turned into a message and sent on the TCP socket.

From my main window I open up a **QFileDialog** when a push-button on the GUI is clicked. Then when a .csv file is navigated to and selected the function reads the .csv file one line at a time, pulls out all the individual parameters, fills the message with the parameters, and then sends it out to the socket. Each message is 28 bytes. It repeats this until there are no lines left in the .csv file.

What I am noticing on Wireshark is that instead of sending a bunch of individual TCP packets they are all being put together and sent as one large TCP packet.

When I first tested this out I did not know about the **LowDelayOption** so when I found the information about it in the documentation for **QAbstractSocket** I thought "Aha! That must be it! The solution to my problem!" but when I added it to my code it did not seem to have any kind of effect at all. It's still being sent as one large TCP packet. For each socket, I am calling **setSocketOption** to set the **LowDelayOption** to 1 in the slot function that receives the **connected()** signal from the socket. I thought maybe the **setSocketOption** call wasn't working so I checked this by calling **socketOption** to get the value of the **LowDelayOption** and it's 1.

Is there something else I need to be doing? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your time and your help. If it matters I am developing this on Windows and I am using Qt 5.9.1

Comment: In addition to setting the LowDelayOption, did you try calling flush() after every send?

Comment: @JamesKPolk calling flush() after every send seemed to do the trick. I somehow missed that function when looking through the Qt documentation for QAbstractSocket Class. Thank you. However sometimes on Wireshark I am seeing a "fast retransmission". I'll have to read up on TCP to see why that is.

Answer (score 1):

From [QTcpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html) documentation:

> TCP (Transmission Control Protocol) is a reliable, **stream-oriented**, connection-oriented transport protocol. It is especially well suited for continuous transmission of data.

Stream-orientet means that there is no something like datagrams in UDP sockets.
There is only stream of data, and you never know in what parts it will be sent.

TCP protocol gives only reliability and you have to provide message extraction on your own. I.e send message length before each message, or use `QDataStream` (check 
[Fortune server](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-example.html) and [Fortune client](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html) for examples).

`LowDelayOption` from [QAbstractSocket::SocketOption](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#SocketOption-enum)

> Try to optimize the socket for low latency. For a QTcpSocket this would set the TCP_NODELAY option and disable [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm). Set this to 1 to enable.

It is equavilent of [setsockopt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx) with `TCP_NODELAY` option
First thing is:

> The TCP_NODELAY option is specific to TCP/IP service providers.

And it doesn't work for me too :)

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx) says that they do not recommend to disable Nagle's algorithm:

> It is highly recommended that TCP/IP service providers enable the Nagle Algorithm by default, and for the vast majority of application protocols the Nagle Algorithm can deliver significant performance enhancements. However, for some applications this algorithm can impede performance, and TCP_NODELAY can be used to turn it off. These are applications where many small messages are sent, and the time delays between the messages are maintained. Application writers should not set TCP_NODELAY unless the impact of doing so is well-understood and desired because setting TCP_NODELAY can have a significant negative impact on network and application performance.

**The question is**: Do you really need to send your messages as fast as possible?
If yes, consider using [QUdpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html). Maybe tell us more about messages that  you are sending.

Answer (score 1):

> ... send and TCP packets to and from a server.

From this I am getting the vibe that your application relies on a certain amount of data - 'a packet' being received in a single receive call.

You can't really rely on that.  Data you send over TCP can also be fragmented on the way. Also in your receiving end TCP implementation multiple packets received from the network may be put in the receiving sockets buffer before you have read the first one, and you have no way of telling which kind of fragments they were originally sent in.

So you should just treat TCP as a pipe through which bytes of data flow with some unknown and potentially variable delay. That variable delay causes data to be received in bigger or smaller chunks at random.

If you want to have a packet structure, you should add a packet header containing at least the packet length to the data you transmit.

I hope this helps.